# How to get the selected value from a selectbox in LinqPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

This example is from the linqpad help file.

```
var yourChoice = new DumpContainer();
string[] colors = { "Red", "Green", "Violet", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow" };

// Dropdown-style select box:
var selectBox = new SelectBox (colors, 0,
    sb => yourChoice.Content = sb.SelectedOption
).Dump ("Choose a color");
yourChoice.Dump ("Your choice(s)");
```

Question1: I can get the selected value using yourChoice.Dump(), but how can I get the selected value as a string?
in the real case scenario the dropdown is a list of customers, after selecting the customer I need to pass the customer name to other methods.

Question2: is there anyway I can set both a submit value and text in the SelectBox, so that the submitted value is different than the displayed value

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by question 2, but for question 1, you can change your action to `sb =>   SelectionChanged(sb.SelectedOption) ` and in the SelectionChanged method cast the parameter from object to string.

Comment: could not get your suggestion to compile, nor sb.SelectionChanged...

Comment: Your questions isn't (exactly) meaningful. You could change the action to save the selected option (`sb.SelectedOption` is a `string`) in a variable, but don't forget that your query stops running before you can interact with the dropdown. How do you envision using the `string`?

Comment: For your second question, if you had a parallel array to `colors` with your values, you could use `sb.SelectedIndex` to pick the value corresponding to the selected color.

Comment: Consider: `var selectBox = new SelectBox(colors, 0,
    sb => sb.SelectedOption.Dump($"Chosen {sb.SelectedOption.GetType()}")
).Dump("Choose a color");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few examples using an array of customers.

You can pass the names to the control and return the name and/or the index of the selected item to your method.

If you can override `ToString()` on your class, then you can just pass your array of customers and pass the selected customer to your method.

```
Customer[] customers ;
void Main()
{
    customers = new Customer[] {
        new Customer{ ID = 1, Name = "Joe Bloggs"},
        new Customer{ ID = 2, Name = "Mary Bloggs"},
        new Customer{ ID = 3, Name = "John Brown"}
    } ;

    var names = customers.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray();
    new LINQPad.Controls.SelectBox(names, 0, sb => SelectionChanged(sb.SelectedOption, sb.SelectedIndex)).Dump("Choose a customer");


    new LINQPad.Controls.SelectBox(customers, 0, sb =>   Selection2Changed(sb.SelectedOption)  ).Dump("Choose a customer");
             
}

void SelectionChanged(object selectedOption, int index)
{
    var selectedName = selectedOption as string;

    Console.WriteLine($"You selected {selectedName}");
    
    customers[index].Dump();
}

void Selection2Changed(object selectedOption)
{
    var selectedCustomer = selectedOption as Customer;


    selectedCustomer.Dump();
}

public class Customer
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use the SelectBox in a procedural way, you could use a TaskCompletionSource:

```
var colors = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Red", "RedValue"},
    { "Violet", "VioletValue"},
    {"Blue", "BlueValue" }
};

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
var selectBox = new SelectBox(colors.Keys.ToArray(), 0, sb =>
{
    tcs.SetResult(colors[sb.SelectedOption.ToString()]);
    sb.Enabled = false;
}).Dump("Choose a color");

var result = await tcs.Task;

result.Dump("Your choice");
```

You could obviously do the same with a `TaskCompletionSource<Customer>` if you override `ToString` as in @sgmoore's answer.

Comment: this did afaik the main trick to understand why the code from the Q was not step or breakpoint debug-able!!